# UI Tag Libraries and Browser Compatability (Specifically Apache Tomahawk & PrimeFaces)

Tags: javascript, browser, primefaces, compatibility, tomahawk

I'm having real trouble finding decent documentation on browser compatibility with these tag libraries... which leads me to believe that I may be asking the wrong questions.

Is there somewhere I can find compatibility information? Or seeing as these components simply render into HTML, CSS and JS are the actual bugs with the browsers?

I've found lots of documented issues with IE 10 and Ajax so obviously there are known issues there.

The problem is that we have two apps that make extensive use of these libraries and since IE 9 we've been having issues with the JavaScript related to the components.

I've been having a look through the Jiras & into the component libraries documentation but these don't seem to offer much help.

Admittedly we are using older versions now, Tomahawk 1.2 and PrimeFaces 3.5, so perhaps it's necessary to update these? ...or spend the time fixing each little compatibility issue as it comes along.

If you have had experience with similar issues please advise.

Answer (score -1):

If you are still stuck having to support older browsers when developing your brand new sites, or even developing sites for an intranet, then chances are you are using the X-UA-Compatible meta tag. It’s that meta tag that you place in your header to let Internet Explorer know to use a certain rendering engine. There are a few issues with it though, best practices